# Traverse XML Structure

Tags: javascript, xml, rhino

I have the following XML doc:

```
<order> 
        <book ISBN="0942407296"> 
            <title>Baking Extravagant Pastries with Kumquats</title> 
            <author> 
                <lastName>Contino</lastName> 
                <firstName>Chuck</firstName> 
            </author> 
            <pageCount>238</pageCount> 
        </book> 
        <book ISBN="0865436401"> 
            <title>Emu Care and Breeding</title> 
            <editor> 
                <lastName>Case</lastName> 
                <firstName>Justin</firstName> 
            </editor> 
            <pageCount>115</pageCount> 
        </book> 
    </order>
```

To get the title for example, I use:

```
myXML.book[0].title[0]
```

How can I get the ISBN (the "0942407296") using the `myXML.book...`?

Comment: You might want to indicate what language you're working in. I'm guessing Javascript, since the expression you've given looks like typical Javascript ugliness...

Comment: Yes, this is javaScript.

Comment: I have figured out and this is the answer: `var final_r= new java.util.ArrayList();
stringBuilder = new java.lang.StringBuilder();
var xml_ISBN= new XML(stringBuilder);
var final_rez = new Array();

//open the XML for reading
var file = new java.io.FileReader (XML_location));

while ((line=file.readLine()) !=null)
{ 

//how many ISBN we have in the XML
if (line.contains ("ISBN"))
counter=counter+1;
}
} `


for (var i=0;i<counter;i++)
{
final_rez[i]=xml_ISBN.book[i];

var convert_str=(xml_ESI.book[i]).toString();

}

Comment: So it's not JavaScript, it's __Java__ -- they are not the same.

Comment: Its Java and JavaScript...Rhino in one word..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var final_r= new java.util.ArrayList(); 
stringBuilder = new java.lang.StringBuilder(); 
var xml_ISBN= new XML(stringBuilder); 
var final_rez = new Array(); 
//open the XML for reading 
var file = new java.io.FileReader (XML_location)); 
while ((line=file.readLine()) !=null) { 
//how many ISBN we have in the XML 
if (line.contains ("ISBN")) counter=counter+1; } 
} 
for (var i=0;i<counter;i++) { 
final_rez[i]=xml_ISBN.book[i]; var convert_str=(xml_ESI.book[i]).toString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// get XML 
var xml = xhr.responseXML;

// get tag
var tags = xml.getElementsByTagName("tagnamehere");
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {   
var tag = tags[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var textNode = document.createTextNode(tag);
td.appendChild(textNode);        
tr.appendChild(td);        
document.getElementById("tbody").appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped!